# How can I tag new orders in Shopify with UTM campaign value

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid, utm-tracking

I'm trying figure out a way to tag all orders (when they're placed) with a piece of UTM data attached to the customer.  So my sub-questions go like this:

Is it possible to use javascript to retrieve source/medium or campaign data from google's tracking code since it's already collecting it?

If not, I'm assuming my best bet is to use liquid to snag UTM values from the URL when the customer first arrives?

With either method, once I've got the value I need, what's the most straight-forward place/method to apply it as a tag to the order? I'd hate to edit the checkout code, but if I must, I must.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

This is a confusing question. When a customer hits your store, Shopify automatically stores the landing page and the reference code that may have been attached to the link the customer used. So the order is in effect already tagged with the code, just in a different place.

If you have some data you want to attach to orders, like a special tag, you can setup a script that listens to orders as they are booked via a webhook. That script would have permissions to make tags on orders, and hence could examine the customer, decide what tag to apply and you'd then have the tag. Basic stuff but not built in to Shopify and not something you'd pull off with Liquid, since Liquid is just rendering your Shop, not for manipulating data of your shop as it happens.

Comment: Basically, I'd like to be able to quickly view/export orders that were attributed to a certain utm_campaign. IE the order was placed during a session where the customer arrived via a link containing 'utm_campaign=xyz'. I assumed tagging would make this easier. 
When you say script, we're not talking a shopify script, right? As I understand, shopify scripts are limited to line-item and shipping discounts?

Comment: I mean using scripts in the sense of an App you'd hook up to your shop and use.